# Use definition file for relative import

Tags: typescript, import, module, momentjs, visual-studio-code

I have two scenarios where the first creates a valid bundle without validly link definition files and the second one creates an invalid bundle but with a valid definition file link.

I'm using Visual Studio Code and rollup for bundling.

#### First scenario - invalid bundle (assumes the dep is external) & valid definition

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

#### Second scenario - invalid definition & valid bundle

```
import moment from 'moment/src/moment'
```

This produces the error `[ts] Cannot find module 'moment/src/moment'` which I've circumvented by declaring the module like:

```
declare module 'moment/src/moment' {
  var m: any;
  export = m;
}
```

How can I find a solution for both? I assume the easiest would be to somehow tell VSCode about the already existing `moment.d.ts` file provided by the `moment` package (which is detected in *scenario 1*).